# C Array Printing Incorrectly Outside of Loop

Tags: c, arrays, loops

I am having an issue where my array will not print out correctly when outside of the loop used for reading in the contents from the file. The code is listed below:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     char *fileArray[78];
     int i, j;
     DIR *d;
     struct dirent *dir;
     char arra[128][128];
     char *arra1[14284][128];
     char line[1024];
     char line1[1024];
     char noiseList[128][128];
     char *noiseList1[14][128];
     char *token;
     char *token1;
     char *path = "./alerts2013/2013/";
     char *path1 = "./Noise_and_Concepts/";
     char *fileName;
     char *fileName1;
     char seps[] = " ,\t\n";
     FILE *myfile;
     FILE *noise;
     int size = 0;
     d = opendir("./alerts2013/2013");
     fileName1 = stradd(path1, "noise.txt");
     //printf("%s\n", fileName1); 
     noise = fopen(fileName1, "r");
     if (noise == 0)
     {
         printf("can not open file \n");
         exit(1);
     }
     int a, b;
     for(a = 0; a < 128; a++) {
         line[a] = '\0';
     }

     for(a = 0; a < 128; a++) {
         for(b = 0; b < 128; b++) {
             noiseList[a][b] = '\0';
             noiseList1[a][b] = '\0';
             arra[a][b] = '\0';
             arra1[a][b] = '\0';
         }
     }  
     i = 0;
     j = 0;
     int k = 0;
     int l = 0;
     int m = 0;
     int n = 0;
     int q;
     int r;
     while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), noise) != NULL) {
         strcpy(noiseList[k], line);
         //printf("%s", noiseList[k]);
         token = strtok(noiseList[k], seps);
         while(token != NULL )
         {
            /* While there are tokens in "string" */
            //printf("%s\n", token);
            //printf("array ----> %s\n", token);

            lower_string(token);
            noiseList1[n][0] = token;
            n++;
            /* Get next token: */
            token = strtok( NULL, seps );

            }
            k++;
       }

       if (d)
       {
            while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL)
            {
                 fileArray[i] = dir->d_name;
                 //printf("%s\n", fileArray[i]);
                 fileName = stradd(path, dir->d_name);
                 //printf("%s\n", fileName);
                 free(fileName);
                 myfile = fopen(fileName,"r");
                 if (myfile == 0)
                 {
                     printf("can not open file \n");
                     exit(1);
                 }

                 for(i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
                     line1[i] = '\0';
                 }

                 if(myfile != NULL) {
                      while(fgets(line1, sizeof(line1), myfile) != NULL) {
                      strcpy(arra[l], line1);
                      //printf("Tokens:\n" );
                      /* Establish string and get the first token: */
                      token = strtok(arra[l], seps);
                      while(token != NULL )
                      {
                           /* While there are tokens in "string" */
                           //printf("%s\n", token);
                           //printf("array ----> %s\n", token);

                           lower_string(token);
                           arra1[m][0] = token;
                           printf("Arra1: %s\n", arra1[m][0]); //PRINTING 
                                                            //CORRECTLY HERE
                           size++;
                           m++;
                           /* Get next token: */
                           token = strtok( NULL, seps );

                      }


                      //printf("array ----> %s ", &arra[i]);
                      i++;

                 }
              }

          fclose(myfile);


          i++;
          }

          closedir(d);
     }

     int p;
     int w;
     printf("%d\n", size);
     /*for(p = 0; p < 14; p++) {
         printf("%s\n", noiseList1[p][0]);
     }*/
     for(w = 0; w < size; w++) { //PRINTING INCORRECTLY HERE
         printf("Arr1 (final): %s\n", arra1[w][0]);
     }

     fclose(noise);
     return(0)
}
```

At the first printf statement not in comments, the array prints correctly. However, at the for loop not in comments at the bottom of the code, it chops off some letters of the string in the array. For example, unauthentication may become ntication. I have no idea why this happening. I don't think my array is saving correctly, but I'm not completely sure. How would I fix this?

Comment: `char *arra1[14284][128];`　: This  seems to be large to secure on the stack.

Comment: It's large because of the amount of files I am required to read in word by word. When I ran the counter to see how many words there were in total, 14284 popped out.

Comment: `free(fileName); myfile = fopen(fileName,"r");` is bad news no matter what's around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mm this is some of the hottest pasta I've ever seen!

`char *arra1[14284][128];` creates (14284*128) character pointers, not 14284 separate 128-character strings. I got the sense that you didn't intend that.

But anyway, `strtok` returns a pointer, which you then assign to [m][0]th pointer of `arra1`. You *never use* 127 pointers for each value of [m] in `arra1`.

I'm not 100% that you can use the pointer that `strtok` returned indefinitely. It looks like that pointer is part of `arra[l]`, which seems to get butchered by a while loop. I don't even see `l` getting incremented! *The program might work if you increment it*.

I think what you really mean to do is create 14284 strings like this:
`char arra1[14284][128];`

then, when you get your `token` after each `strtok`, you should `strcpy(arra1[m], token)`.

Comment: I don't have enough rep to comment on your post so I'll comment on mine- I highly recommend you read [The Essential C](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/101/EssentialC.pdf) from Stanford and understand the [] and * operators and how they can be interchanged.

What the other user said about *arra1[14284][128] not being something you can secure on the stack- I don't know. The compiler and the OS should know how big the .data/.bss section is so I think it would throw a descriptive error if it had to. This whole algorithm might be better served by learning how to use `malloc()` and `realloc()`

Comment: Thank you! Changing "arra1[m][0] = token" to "strcpy(arra1[m], token)" worked!

Comment: You can change the type of `arra1` from `char *` to `char` for posterity. Also, realize you're making a *copy* so as long as you protect the `array1[m]` from getting altered explicitly, you can trash all the variables you used to create it if they aren't tracking something else important. This in mind, you can reduce the space of your program. edit: also look at `strcpy_s()`- it's safer